# How do I change the individual value to be summed during annotation in Django?

Tags: django, django-filter

I am front end developer new to django. There is a certain column(*server_reach*) in our postgres DB which has values of (1,2). But I need to write a query which tells me if at least one of the filtered rows has a row with reachable values( 1= not reachable, 2 = reachable).

I was initially told that the values of the column would be (0,1) based on which I wrote this:

```
ServerAgent.objects.values('server').filter(
    app_uuid_url=app.uuid_url,
    trash=False
).annotate(serverreach=Sum('server_reach'))
```

The logic is simple that I fetch all the filtered rows and annotate them with the sum of the server_reaches. If this is more than zero then at least one entry is non-zero.

But the issue is that the actual DB has values (1,2). And this logic will not work anymore. I want to subtract the server_reach of each row by '1' before summing. I have tried F expressions as below

```
ServerAgent.objects.values('server').filter(
    app_uuid_url=app.uuid_url,
    trash=False
).annotate(serverreach=Sum(F('server_reach')-1))
```

But it throws the following error. Please help me getting this to work.

```
AttributeError: 'ExpressionNode' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Avg` instead of `Sum`.  If average value is greater than 1 then at least one row contains value of 2.

Comment: Thanks man. Thats pretty creative. Did not think of that at all. One a different note, The F expression is not working. Any thoughts on that?